# How to specify NULL for SSRS parameter when building a report string

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, nullable

I have an SSIS package job that takes a report link and generates a PDF file. I don't think I need to go into the details of that job, other than to say, it takes a report link that looks something like this and generates a PDF file to a specified location.

[image]

My question is this.

The last part of the string above that is highlighted red is how the report parameter is specified. How do I change this if I need to pass NULL for the parameter value? This parameter happens to allow NULL but not sure how I can specify NULL value when I am building out this string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
ReportParameter:isnull=true
```